# Moment.js timezone conversion C# .NET

Tags: datetime, timezone, momentjs, date-conversion, nodatime

Is there an available c# plugin that handles all the moment.js timezones.

I am having a hard time comparing the dates in the backend since the timezones from moment.js is not the same as the timezones from the .net DateTime.

I need to convert the times to Utc before comparing the different timezoned dates. 
I am using nodatime and it is able to handle some of the timezones but not all.

Thanks.

EDIT:
NodaTime handled most of the timezones but I still need to cover the abbrevations. Is there something available for this?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you convert an moment.js datetime to utc? This could be parsed by nodatime-

Comment: thanks. I found nodatime but I still have problems dealing with Timezone Abbrevs. Is there other ways to get timezone via abbrev? e.g. ACST = Australian Central Standard Time

Comment: You could find *all* the time zones which ever use a particular abbreviation, but you'd be better off avoiding abbreviations entirely. Doesn't moment.js give you the full IANA ID, e.g. Europe/London?

Comment: @Milo - It's unclear what you're talking about.  Please show a code example.  You can't get an abbreviation out of moment without going through moment-timezone and specifying an IANA time zone id. Also, please recognize that many time zone abbreviations are ambiguous.  For example, there are 5 different meanings of "CST".  [See this list for more examples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations).

Comment: @Jon - Moment doesn't *give* you the IANA time zone ID, you have to supply it, and only when using the moment-timezone plugin.  Ex:  `moment().tz('Europe/London').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss zz') === "2014-09-23 21:37:24 BST"`

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I was also confused. I thought the selection I had, which had options from Olson to Abbrevs to GMT+0, were from moment.js but it seems they were static data from that was copied from iana. My problem now is handling abbrevations since it is being used in the application

Comment: @JonSkeet Oh, you're part of the dev team for NodaTime. I have a list of abbrevations that NodaTime missed. How can I give this to you? e.g. ACST = Australian Central Standard Time was not mapped to Australia...

Comment: It's not that Noda Time "missed" anything - it's a matter of what's available in TZDB (IANA). But again, I would *strongly* urge you to abandon abbreviations entirely. They're ambiguous and basically painful - even if it means a fair amount of work to pull them out (or at least only use them for display purposes) I'd strongly urge you to do so.

Comment: I can't necessarily back off of this since the downstream that will use the data is already using this since its java and it isn't even a problem for them there

Comment: Anything that uses abbreviations *does* have a problem - they may just not realize it yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So NodaTime handled the Olson Timezones as well as GMT+ , UTC and others. For the abbrevations, I settled with this

```
public static DateTimeZone GetTimeZone(string id)
    {
        DateTimeZone timezone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb.GetZoneOrNull(id);

        if (timezone == null) {
            var instant = Instant.FromDateTimeUtc(DateTime.UtcNow);
            var source = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb;
            id = source.Ids.Where(i => source[i].GetZoneInterval(instant).Name == id).FirstOrDefault();
            timezone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb.GetZoneOrNull(id);
        }

        return timezone;
    }
```